# How to remove this type of pixels

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

How to remove this type of pixels

**Examples :**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try morphological transformations such as Opening or Erosion.

This is the documentation of OpenCV where you can find more information.
https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html

It's hard to tell which method would give better results without knowing anything more specific.